# Debug some cpp files in one project (VS2015)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So I have 2 cpp files in 1 project. And I want debug first and then debug second.
1st cpp prints "HEllo" and second - "HELLOWORLD".
Is there any way to debug these two cpp files independently?

Comment: @Ryan I do not know what is it

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when multiple processes are running in the debugger, the breaking, stepping, and stopping debugger commands usually affect all the processes. For example, when one process is suspended at a breakpoint, the execution of all other processes is also suspended. You can change this default behavior to gain more control over the targets of execution commands.
On the Debug menu, choose Options and Settings.
On the Debugging, General page, clear the Break all processes when one process breaks check box.